# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE -- on the device

Tags: android

I have a situation here with a problem of not sufficient place in device. I have been looking for answer to this question here and found quiet a lot of answers, which is not acceptable, because:
1. They are all talking about emulator, in my case its real test device
2. Community suggested to increase storage, so there will not be anymore like this message -- what i did is i deleted few apps/games in device, so it helped, but after few runs from eclipse directly to device, the message started to appear again.

As at the beginning app (apk) uploads to the device and then installing, I assume eclipse cant delete previous app (apk), so it keeps copying the new ones without deleting the old ones. Is there any way to clean that apks, or im thinking totally wrong.
Help.
Thanks, and so sorry if the answer is somewhere here and i didnt find it.

Comment: Reinstalling the App does not clean Data which was generated by your app. So does your App create lot of data on the device? Then clean the App data in the settings. Btw have you checked if your phone has relay no storage space left or if this is a bug?

Comment: @Christian S.
My app doesnt create any additional data. It is 10 mb. And yes, my phone really has no free space on internal storage, so what i did is i deleted few apps, but it keeps making it full, so i cant delete everything from phone.

Answer (score 2):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.packagename.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

It got resolved by this way

Comment: By the above code snippet will it surely store the application in SD card or will it only **prefer** to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to do two things after which this error will be resolved. 

1. In your AndroidManifest.xml file add android:installLocation="preferExternal" within your manifest      tag.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.packagename.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal">

2. More importantly, clear the cache data in your device. Goto settings -> storage -> click on cached data. This will clear the cache and free the space. 

3. Reconnect your device, clean your project and again run it on the device. The project will now run on    your device.
```